# Delaying the Observable

Tags: angular, observable

I am working on one scenario like " Requires to call one Dummy get Api call before every Post call in application".

**Note : 1. Actual post call should start once after completion of dummy get call.**
                                                                                                         **2. Requires to solve the problem by editing the code only in service file.**

Here is my problem ,

Component.ts

```
this._service.dopost().subscribe(
  data => { console.log(data); });
```

Service.ts

```
   dopost() {
         this._http.get(dammyUrl, body, {
            observe: "response",
            headers: headers 
          }).subscribe((responce)=>{
            return this._http.post(url, body, {
               observe: "response",
               headers: headers 
            });
          });

  }
```

Stack blitz Link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qa1ztz

Comment: what response are you expecting in your component?

Comment: @bryan60 I would like to get the response of post call in component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [SwitchMap Operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

> Map to observable, complete previous inner observable, emit values.

```
dopost():SecondResponseType  {
    return this._http.get<InitialResponseType>('dammyUrl', {}, {
        observe: 'response',
        headers: {} 
        }).pipe(
            switchMap((initialResponse: InitialResponseType) => this._http.post<SecondResponseType>('url', {}, {
                observe: "response",
                headers: {} 
            }))
        });
}
```

As soon as you subscribe to `depost()` method 2 requests will be executed consequently.

if you use [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule), your method looks simpler. Practically, HttpClientModule is a wrapper around HttpModule

```
dopost(): Observable<SecondResponseType>  {
    return this._http.get<SecondResponseType>('dammyUrl').pipe(
        switchMap((initialResponse: InitialResponseType) => this._http.post<SecondResponseType>('url'))
    });
}
```

Comment: Great ! .. Thanks .!

Comment: Sure. Just keep in ming @Narayanan that unless you don't need headers in response, its easier to use HttpClientModule rather than HttpModule. Gonna change my answer accordingly...

Comment: @Timorthy I am using httpClient module. But I am not covered in question.  As we are in latest  version of angular, HttpClient Module is recommended  to use.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need in this case [`flatMap` RxJS operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap). See example below:

```
dopost() {
      return this._http.get(dammyUrl, body, {
         observe: "response",
         headers: headers 
       }).pipe(flatMap(responce=>{
         return this._http.post(url, body, {
            observe: "response",
            headers: headers 
          });
       }));
}
```

And you have to subscribe to the `dopost` method as it is described in the question.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qa1ztz - I have tried like the way you told . Its throwing the exception in component.

Comment: Sorry, I left a `return` out, I updated the response. See stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-35l4xf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmyservice.ts